# angular material - labels overlap with the input

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material, angular6, ngoninit

I utilize `Angular 6` with `Angular Material`.

Problem: **the labels overlap with the input when browser *auto-populates* the fields**.

I tried to replicate the issue with `stackblitz` but didn't have much luck.

Attaching screenshot for more details

[image]

There are no issues listed in chrome console tab.

My `LoginComponent` is lacking `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterInit` - I don't have any code for those methods at the moment.

Perhaps I've misunderstood the concept of how controls are supposed to be initialized on page load.

Anyone solved this already?

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz for it in order for us to help you?

Comment: Hi @AnkitSharma, I've just tried to replicate it populating fields in `ngOnInit` & `ngAfterInit` - but it works fine. The issue occurs when browser auto-populates the fields. I don't think this is something I can replicate with `stackblits`. Pardon. (updated the post)

Comment: @AnkitSharma https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x3kudh

Comment: @AnkitSharma I also tried to provide an input with text using `value` attribute in debugger's `DOM browser`. But that doesn't populate the field with text.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I tried recreating, however unfortunately, I could not autopopulate and hence cannot arrive at a solution. However, can you try to set again the password field with the password itself once the username changes and see if it works after auto populating?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Just did. I removed all the text from both fields. And then entered first letter in username - a popup suggestion shows up - then I picked username and it auto-populated password. 
But in this case everything works fine - no overlapping labels.

Comment: Hence, no error :P

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are referencing a Material theme; either your own or one of the pre-built Material themes.

As per [the guidance for referencing a pre-built theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme) you need to add your chosen theme's css file to the styles array in your angular.json.

So your angular.json would look like the following if you chose the pre-built **indigo pink** theme

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "demo": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
          "outputPath": "dist/demo",
          "index": "src/index.html",
          "main": "src/main.ts",
          "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
          "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
          "styles": [
            "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
            "src/styles.css"
          ],
          "scripts": []
      },
```

Notice how the styles array now has the path to the indigo-pink.css file included.

The presence of the theme will fix the styling issue you describe.